# WinForms Webbrowser control Not playing Videos

Tags: winforms, video, webbrowser-control

I am using WinForms Webbrowser control in my application.
I am navigating this control to following url:

https://medlineplus.gov/ency/anatomyvideos/000002.htm

This web page has one video embedded in it.
But my WinForms Webbrowser control is unable to play this video.
But if I open the same url in IE11 installed on my machine it works well.
Can somebody explain why WinForms Webbrowser is unable to play this video.